# How to divide an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-organization, asp.net-mvc-areas

I need to provide a brand new interface to an already existing MVC app.  A lot of it will be the same, a lot will be different.  I've thought of four ways to do this, but I don't really like any them.

*Can someone provide a good basis for choosing an option?*

1. **Two applications**: We create an entirely new MVC app, new domain (or subdomain), new everything.  We might use the same data access library, but in terms of the web interface they are completely independent.
2. **MVC Areas**: We use the same application but create a *Employees* area and a *Customers* area.  We use some type of Role based routing to decide which area a request belongs to.
3. **Conditional Controller Statements**: We examine the request inside each controller method and decide what data to return.
4. **Partial Views**: One app, one area.  We put conditional checks inside the views to decide which partial to render (either the customer one or the employee one).

## More Details

We use a working MVC 3 app in our business for all of our office management needs.  It includes features for employee time, purchase orders, customer management and history, etc.  There's a wealth of customer information in there that our customers would love to see like their purchase history, reports on how much they spent, etc.  We obviously do not want to just open our system up to them.  It has a lot of internal data we do not want them to see, and we do not want them to be able to modify anything.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split your solutions in different projects ?

I like to use the proxy pattern.

In my solution I have three projects:

- MVC (Has a reference to Proxy project)
- Proxy (It is a class library, hold's a reference to a WCF project)
- WCF (This project knows the database, my Entity Framework is here)

I guess this image could be helpful:

[image]

With this approach you can have different repositories in your proxy project, you can swap between them. It is extremely helpful when we are unit testing, or when we need to use cached repositories.

```
public abstract class Repository<T>
{
    public abstract T GetById(int id);
}
```

Use this one for unit testing

```
public class CustomerRepository : Repository<CustomerEntity>
{
    public override CustomerEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return new CustomerEntity()
                    {
                       Id = id,
                       Name = "Customer " + id
                   };
    }
}
```

Use this one when you need to access external services

```
public class RemoteOrderRepository : Repository<OrderEntity>
{
    public override OrderEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        // You can access your external service here
    }
}
```

Use this one to take advantage of caching

```
public class CachedOrderRepository : RemoteOrderRepository
{
    public override OrderEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        string cacheKey = "Order" + id;
        var entity = MemoryCache.Default[cacheKey] as OrderEntity;
        if(entity == null)
        {
            entity = base.GetById(id);
            var cacheItem = new CacheItem(cacheKey, entity);
            var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheItem, policy);
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```